# How to apply filter on chrome.windows.onFocusChanged

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to apply filter as specified by
[google doc for chrome.windows.onFocusChanged](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#event-onFocusChanged).
How can i do this?

Comment: chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(yourListener, {windowTypes: ['normal', 'popup']})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General documentation is at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#filtered

```
// In general, it looks like this:
chrome.apiName.onEventName.addListener(handler, filter);
```

Note:

> Events support specific filters that are meaningful to that event. The list of filters that an event supports will be listed in the documentation for that event in the "filters" section.

So, from the [docs for `windows.onFocusChanged`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#event-onFocusChanged):

> #### Filters
>
> array of [WindowType](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#type-WindowType) `windowTypes`
>
> Conditions that the window's type being removed must satisfy. By default it satisfies `['normal', 'popup']`.

In your case, as suggested by wOxxOm:

```
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(yourListener, {windowTypes: ['normal', 'popup']});
```

The only other non-deprecated [window type](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#type-WindowType) option is `'devtools'`.

Unfortunately, you can't add a filter on any other conditions. You'd need to check in the handler if you wish to filter by something like window ID, condition on the window state, tabs, etc.

Comment: done the same, but not working.
it still gets triggered for some window id '-1'.

Comment: Or its the dev tools window??

Comment: but i'm not opening dev tools window outside the main window.

Comment: @SahilBansal "Returns `chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_NONE` if all Chrome windows have lost focus." I'm willing to bet this constant is -1.